# How to use own keystore in WSO2 AM (1.10.0)

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

In order to add a CA signed certificate into WSO2 AM in production. I create a new keystore,

```
keytool -genkey -alias puaki -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore puaki.jks -dname "CN=puaki.mpi.govt.nz,OU=BTIS,O=MPI,L=Christchurch,ST=Canterbury,C=NZ" -storepass password -keypass Ferns1de -validity 730
```

then create a certificate request,

```
keytool -certreq -alias puaki -keyalg RSA -keystore puaki.jks -storepass passsword -file cacertreq.csr
```

I send this csr file to system admins who provide a singed certificate along with a root certificate and intermediate certificates. The new keystore (puaki.jks) will import those certificates. I am not very clear how to make this keystore working for WSO2 AM. Currently I only simply import this puaki.jks through UI as below,

[image: UI]

I have no idea if I also have to change configurations and add CA certificate as a trusted certificate followed by the article, http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/2011/08/adding-ca-certificate-authority-signed-certificate-wso2-products/

Thanks,
Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the steps provided in [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon443/Creating+New+Keystores) to create the keystore and steps in [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon443/Configuring+Keystores+in+WSO2+Products) configure the keystore.